# Russian visa in one day for US Citizens in Europe

Tags: visas, us-citizens, russia

I have 5 guys from USA on tour. They wasted time to apply for Russian visa in USA and now they are touring around the whole world. They will be in: Australia, France, Italy, Uk, Germany, etc. How can they get Russian visas in one day in one of these countries?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How can these guys get russian visa in only one day in one of these countries?

Comment: Are they all US citizens?

Comment: Yes, they are .

Comment: The short answer is they cannot. US Citizens/Residents of the US must apply through the private company [Invisa Logistics Services LLC](http://www.ils-usa.com) Foreign Nationals in the US can use the US offices, but I haven't found the opposite being true (US Citizens in other countries). Russia has outsourced all of their visa applications in all countries (in your list) and none of them have one day service.

Comment: @CGCampbell thanks for answer. Do you know, can they apply by mail and get visas when they will be in one of these countries? And how much time it usually takes? Or can they apply and get visas later by mail while being in another country?

Comment: It can vary from country to country.  3 days minimun in the US and 2 in Australia.  You will need to check in the respective consulates.

Comment: @Karlson thank you! I will contact this Invisa Logistics Services company

Comment: As an USA citizen residing in the UK, I had to obtain Russian visa several times in the past.  Generally speaking, Russian consulate will not issue a visa to a non-resident of the country.  As I was applying from the UK, I had to prove that I actually am resident in the UK and that I had at least 3 months left on my resident visa. As a separate note, a US citizen can apply by post, but they would have to send (among other things) their passport, which is rather not possible if they are travelling through multiple countries.

Comment: @AleksG, Spot on. I agree with you.  As a minor detail, there is a coffee shop near the corner of Bayswater Road and Ossington Street where the proprietor will take your passport and documents around to the service entrance of the Russian Embassy and get your visa in the same day.  I only know for sure about London, but it's likely there are similar arrangements globally.

Comment: @GayotFow Somehow I don't think that's quite an official way of obtaining a visa...

Comment: @MichaelHampton, you may be right. in the era when I needed visas it was standard practice... Upon arrival I always got the standard 90 seconds without any hassles

Answer (score 3):

You're likely out of luck.  Generally, Russia requires you apply for a visa (and needs an invitation as well) from your country of citizenship OR country of residence.

If you're not applying at the embassy/consulate in your home country, you have to prove (visa or otherwise) that you're a resident in the third party country.

Getting an invite is easy enough, there are websites that do that for you, but to get it all in one day - no, and to get the visa from a non-residence country - unlikely, unless you can find a specialist visa agency who can pull some strings, like [VHS in Germany](http://www.vhs-germany.com/contacts/).